# Remove all paired Bluetooth devices from iPhone in one go

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I'd like to remove a long list of old devices I paired to an iPhone without having to remove them one by one (I've got like 30 devices saved). I tried resetting Network settings followed by Reset All Settings but to no avail, they're still there!. Any way to do it without having to erase the iPhone?

I just need to know if there's an Apple official way to do it, so to speak, not any third party app or method.

Comment: Resetting “network settings” should removed remembered devices. Perhaps try again with Bluetooth off.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the only soluction is to erase all contents and settings

Comment: Please do not follow this answer, this is quite extreme and resetting your device is not needed.

Answer (score -3):

The way to do this is:

Shift-Option-Click your bluetooth icon. This brings up the Debug. You will see three options in the attached image.

`Remove all devices` is your one stop removal.

`Reset the Bluetooth module` is the factory reset option.

[image: Screenshot of bluetooth Debug menu options]

Comment: How does one Shift-Option-Click in iOS and where is the Bluetooth icon to click on? The question's title is "Remove all paired Bluetooth devices from iPhone in one go" and your answer is for macOS and not applicable here.